# Is CocoaPods incompatible with MacOS Ventura?

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoapods

Two completely different error modes while installing CocoaPods on two different MacOS Ventura machines, one Intel and the other M1.  MacOS 13.3.1 and Xcode 14.3.1.

I've explored some of the posted suggestions, each of which seems to dig me into a deeper rabbit hole. Before trying to spend time pursuing this, or ditching CocoaPods completely, this is just to ask if Ventura is considered to be a supported platform for this project (or, in fact, if the project continues to be supported at all). I had expected that the installation steps on the CocoaPods site would be up to date and accurate.

Not seeking to find a hack for a specific error here, just asking about general compatibility and support.

Comment: What Ruby are you using?

Comment: Ruby is 2.6.10p210, no change to what is pre-installed.

Comment: That's the problem. You need to stop using the system ruby. You should never have been using it, and now you're busted. No problem, just use rbenv to install and configure your own ruby and you'll be all set.

Comment: I guess one would need to ask, why would CocoaPods be incompatible with the system ruby -- this being the one and only platform CocoaPods targets?

Comment: From cocoapods.org: "CocoaPods is built with Ruby and it will be installable with the default Ruby available on macOS. You can use a Ruby Version manager, however we recommend that you use the standard Ruby available on macOS unless you know what you're doing."

Comment: I don't care whether you believe me. I have no skin in the game; pods are working fine for me. You're the one with the problem.

Answer (score -1):

Following up on matt's suggestions, I dug in a bit more and found success with this by installing a newer Ruby version in parallel, in spite of the advice on cocoapods.org not to do so.

There are several ways to do this; I chose the approach of using brew to install ruby and then editing PATH to prefer the newer Ruby for my own user. This allows the pre-installed "system ruby" to remain intact for any existing purposes.

Note that the installed location will depend on whether it's an Intel or an Apple Silicon Mac. On Intel, the update to .zshrc is:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/opt/ruby/bin:$PATH
export PATH=`gem environment gemdir`/bin:$PATH
```

After this update, "sudo gem install cocoapods" succeeds, on both platforms.  The final combination is MacOS 13.3.1, Xcode 14.3.1, and Ruby 3.2.2.

Comment: No, if you have to say `sudo` you're still doing it wrong.

Comment: Anyway this whole discussion just duplicates lots of existing questions with answers such as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67445542/error-installing-cocoapods-failed-to-build-gem-native-extensio. We really don't need another one.